# Uploading images in node.js results in corrupt files

Tags: node.js, image, express, file-upload, multer

I want to save an image to my node.js folder.

**Save function:**

```
function saveBrochure(brochure, image, file) {
  return uploadBrochure(file).then(
    data => {
      uploadImage(image);
      return brochureModel.addBrochure(brochure);
    },
    error => {
      return error;
    }
  );
}
```

**upload function**:

```
function uploadImage(image) {
  var path = 'my-path/' + image.filename;
  fs.writeFile(path, image, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}
```

My image object looks like this

```
destination:"path"
encoding:"7bit"
fieldname:"image"
filename:"filename"
mimetype:"image/png"
originalname:"filename"
path:"path/filename.png"
size:155217
```

After the upload, I can see that a corrupted image file has been added to my project.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is `image`? How do you get it?

Comment: It's send from my angular front-end, I handle it in my router with `multer`